# Expired certificate for Java Web Start

Tags: java, security, cryptography, java-web-start

How does JWS react to code signing certificate expiration?

From my observation it appears to ignore expiration date of CA-signed certificates, but I would like to find some hard proof (e.g. official documentation) that confirms this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the signed jar is given a timestamp (which comes from a timestamp authority), then the signature will still be valid even after the certificate has expired (assuming the timestamp is prior to the expiry).

See [Signature Timestamp Support for J2SE 5.0](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/time-of-signing.html)