# Why am I not getting any warnings about my java web start application that is signed with an expired certificate?

Tags: java, certificate, code-signing, java-web-start

I have a java web start application (I deploy a war to Tomcat, user goes to the website and downloads a jnlp which then can be executed). In my build process the **jars are signed using a CA authority signed certificate** and as far as I can tell without timestamping. The certificate has **recently expired**.

Extracting jars from the war file and checking them using jarsigner shows:

```
jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired. 
This jar contains signatures that do not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after any of the signer certificates expire (as early as 2020-02-24).
```

It appears that:

- the users can still launch the java web start applications
- the build job still runs and is able to sign with the expired certificate
- deploying a newly built version that has been signed with the expired certificate still works and the app still launches

Now I am wondering what is the impact of that expiry, and should I even bother with renewing the certificate and adding to the keystore?

**Update:**

Server:

- Tomcat Version Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
- JVM Version 1.8.0_181-b13

Client:

- Java Web Start 11.121.2.13 x86
- Using JRE version 1.8.0_121-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

Comment: I am aware of this question which has an answer for the case where a timestamp is used when signing, but that does not apply for my application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869946/expired-certificate-for-java-web-start

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? We are also facing the same issue.